# Finding digit position

Tags: c, recursion

I am to write a **recursive** function `int digitpos(int num, int digit)` which takes in a positive integer `num` and `digit` which returns the position of first appearance of `digit` in `num` from the right starting from 1. If not found, `0` will be returned.

For example, `digitPos(12234, 2`) would yield `3` and `digitpos(123, 8)` would yield `0`

```
int digitPos(int n, int digit)
{   
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n % 10 == digit) return 1;
    return 1 + digitPos(n / 10, digit);
}
```

The above works if the digit exists in the number. If it doesn't, it will print out how many digits are there(as it goes through all digits).

It don't seems to me to be possible to do so by recursion given only these 2 parameters. Sure, by iteration I can do it. But I wanna know is it possible through recursion?

Comment: Your code does not work even if the digit exists. Try your example. `digitPos(12234,2)` returns 1, not 3. This is obviously homework, and I am not going to do your homework for you. I will give a hint. The answer is yes, it is possible. You might need more than one function.

Comment: @DavidHammen. I have got the values in the example mixed out earlier. I have since edited it. Yes this might be my school work. But what is wrong if I did try something and asked along the way. Not like I just throw the question without trying?

Comment: "If it doesn't, it will print out how many digits are there"??? Your code doesn't print anything!!!

Comment: Is `digit` a digit (i.e., an integer between 0 and 9, inclusive), or can it be any non-negative number? The reason I ask is that you had `digitPos(8,123)` in an earlier revision of the question, and the wording of the problem suggests that it might not be a "digit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can be written for example the following way

```
int digitPos( unsigned int n, unsigned int digit )
{   
    if ( n % 10 == digit ) return 1;

    if ( ( n /= 10 ) == 0 ) return 0;

    int i = digitPos( n, digit );

    return i == 0 ? 0 : i + 1;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digitPos( unsigned int n, unsigned int digit )
{   
    if ( n % 10 == digit ) return 1;

    if ( ( n /= 10 ) == 0 ) return 0;

    int i = digitPos( n, digit );

    return i == 0 ? 0 : i + 1;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d\n", digitPos( 12345, 2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
4
```

Take into account that 0 is a valid digit.:)

Comment: It doesn't work for digits that doesn't exist in the number still. It should print 0 if digit does not exist. Try `digitpos(123, 8)` it should give 0 instead of 3

Comment: @MaTaKazer I do not know what program you are speaking about. Did you run the function that is sown in my post?

Comment: Alright it works as intended. Sorry... Got confused with all the naming when I copied and paste into VS.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 int count=1;
 int digitPos(int n, int digit)
{
if(n==0) { count=0; return 0;}
if (n % 10 == digit) return 1;
count++;
digitPos(n/10, digit );
return count;
}
int main(void){
 printf("%d",digitPos(12234,8));
 return 0;
}
```

You don't have to divide `digit` by 10 as it will always give 0, instead divide `n` by 10.

Comment: Will this not return 1 if the digit is *not* in `n` as well? And there is no check on `n` -- I think it will happily go on recursively returning 1's long after the number is zeroed out.

Comment: @karma_geek I have edited my question. Please take a look again.

Comment: @MaTaKazer: Which one is correct: `digitPos(2, 12234)` or  `digitpos(123,8)`?

Comment: @karma_geek `digitPos(12234, 2)`would yield `3` and `digitpos(123, 8)` would yield `0`

Comment: @karma_geek I see that you used a global var counter. I forgotten to state that you are only suppose to define the function and not change any other part of the program. The other user provided a good answer to my problem. Thanks anyway though!